# React Native release build unable to access .env file on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

Everything works fine on debug but on release build, no variable in my .env files is accessible. They all appear as undefined.

`"react-native": "0.71.7",`
`"react-native-config": "^1.5.0",`

I build using the following: `react-native run-android --mode=release` or `react-native run-android --variant=release`

Here are my codes:
// ../app/build

```
// Load gradle.properties
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('.gradle/gradle.properties')
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        debug: '.env',
        release: '.env',
        stagingrelease: '.env.staging',
        productionrelease: '.env.production'
]

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + '/dotenv.gradle' //react-native-config

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle' // react-native-vector-icons
/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {}

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.myPageName"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myPageName"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD']
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        stagingrelease {
            initWith release
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

        productionrelease {
            initWith release
            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

// proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

-keep class com.myPackageName.BuildConfig { *; }
```

My AndroidManifest.xml does not have a package name

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
```

Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is the .env.production file populated?